# Java loads wrong resource

Tags: java, resources, properties, locale

I have this 2 properties files in my resources folder:
**messages_hr_HR.properties** and **messages.properties**

I don't use javas's Locale class I use mine custom Locale class:

```
public class Locale {

    private String bundleName;
    private String localeName;
    private String iconPath;

    public Locale(String bundleName, String localeName, String iconPath) {
        super();

        this.bundleName = bundleName;
        this.localeName = localeName;
        this.iconPath = iconPath;
    }

    public String getBundleName() {
        return bundleName;
    }
    public void setBundleName(String bundleName) {
        this.bundleName = bundleName;
    }
    public String getLocaleName() {
        return localeName;
    }
    public void setLocaleName(String localeName) {
        this.localeName = localeName;
    }

    public String getIconPath() {
        return iconPath;
    }

    public void setIconPath(String iconPath) {
        this.iconPath = iconPath;
    }
}
```

I have Messages class with static method to return the value of the key:

```
public class Messages {

    private Messages() {
        // do not instantiate
    }


    private static List<Locale> availableLocales;
    private static Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("messages.messages", "EN", "/images/icons/locale/en.png");
    static {
        availableLocales = new ArrayList<Locale>();

        availableLocales.add(defaultLocale);
        availableLocales.add(new Locale("messages.messages_hr_HR", "HR", "/images/icons/locale/hr.png"));   
    }

    private static Locale LOCALE = defaultLocale;
    private static ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = loadBundle();
    private static ResourceBundle loadBundle() {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle(LOCALE.getBundleName());
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            ResourceBundle bundle = RESOURCE_BUNDLE == null ? loadBundle() : RESOURCE_BUNDLE;
            return bundle.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return "!" + key + "!";
        }
    }

    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        LOCALE = locale;
        RESOURCE_BUNDLE = loadBundle();
    }

    public static Locale getLocale() {
        return LOCALE;
    }
    public static List<Locale> getAvailableLocales() {

        return availableLocales;
    }
}
```

Then in my GUI I have radiobutton menu with available languages and when user clicks on some I just call `Messages.setLocale(clickedLanguageLocale);`

So you can see that I am responsible of loading specific file, not java.

Problem is that on some computers it acts strange. Some text is on english (messages.properties) and some on croatian (messages_hr_HR). First thing that got on my mind was some OS default locale but it does not make any sense since I use mine classes.

Any ideas for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to guess the order in which the messages are loaded without seeing the entire code.
My guess is there is a data race on RESOURCE_BUNDLE if multiple threads are involved in your GUI application.
The GUI starts reading the new text-keys before the new RESOURCE_BUNDLE has been loaded. 
That is why part of them appear in English while the rest in Croatian.

Edit: This turned out to be the actual solution as noted in the comment below:

Also, you can use this version of getBundle() docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/… to explicitly pass the Locale you want to use.

Comment: Hmm, maybe because of those static loading? But I don't think that's the problem because GUI has to load in order to choose which language I want. So if GUI is loaded, resources are also loaded. And then in GUI class I have listener on that radiobutton group: `localeMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     Messages.setLocale(locale);
     setStringValues();
    }
   });` I set the new locale.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it might be an issue with the fact that you are using the default getBundle(). Read up on the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29 . getBundle() will use the default java.util.Locale in the user's system and not necessarily the one you mention as the default in your Locale class.

Comment: Maybe this could be the problem. How can I load a bundle with its name? But another thing that is strange is that HR locale does not exist in Locale class and somehow `getBundle()` method decides to take it as default.

Comment: You can use java.util.Locale.getAvailableLocales() to find out the locales supported in the user's system.

Comment: Also, you can use this version of getBundle() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29 to explicitly pass the Locale you want to use.

Comment: Well I refactored code now to use specific locale (I use now java's Locale) so I'll try it tomorrow at college to see if this is the problem.

Comment: I voted yours comment because that is where I found the solution. I had to use combination of mine custom locale which has 2 fields: iconPath and java.util.Locale. Now it works perfect, I just tested it on that computers at college.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug with breakpoint at  `String getString(String key)` for keys that result english messages?

Comment: The thing is that on my computer it behaves normally as expected. That other computers are at my college (my profesor) so I can't just go there and install Eclipse there to debug :S